# owl carousel slider not working with rtl

Tags: html, owl-carousel

I have a problem with the owl carousel slider.

When my html page opening tag is: `<html>` , the slider works fine and I can see the images.

But when my page opening is: `<html dir="rtl">`, the slider is not working, I mean I see arrows, and pagination but not the pictures itself:

here is my code:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            navigation : false,
            rtl:true,
            slideSpeed : 300,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            singleItem:true
          });
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JS, just put `rtl: true`. It worked for me.

```
$id.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: false,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    rtl: true
});
```

Answer (score 22):

Put this code in css file

```
.owl-carousel,
.bx-wrapper { direction: ltr; }
.owl-carousel .owl-item { direction: rtl; }
```

Comment: Perfect answer and straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

No need to manually add custom CSS rules anywhere (especially that direction: ltr)...

**Owl Carousel v2.3.4**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true // add this to the rest of the options
});
```

After adding that, Owl Carousel automatically appends an '**owl-rtl**' class to the carousel HTML element, and then the plugin's CSS rules will automatically trigger **rtl** functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You should put

```
direction: rtl
// maybe even
text-align: right // not sure if necessary
```

on the parent element of the slider.
This should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for comment, it works ! thank you and sorry for the belated reply from me !

Comment: Actually I had to do the opposite, I had to add "direction: ltr;" to the container.

Answer (score 4):

solution 1: Please try this js Code

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

solution 2: Please try this css Code

```css
.owl-carousel,
.bx-wrapper { direction: ltr; }
.owl-carousel .owl-item { direction: rtl; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **owlCarousel** then only add this **rtl: true,** in js file .

```
       $('.hero-slide').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            margin: 0,
            autoplay: true,
            nav: true,
            dots: true,
            rtl: true,
            navText: ['<span class="icon-arrow_back">', '<span 
            class="icon-arrow_forward">'],
            smartSpeed: 1000
        });
```